# writing-mode: vertical-rl is not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML Table with some td's with property: writing-mode: vertical-rl. On the laptop it's working fine with all browsers, but on the mobile it is not (I tried both Safari and Chrome), and it's not working
What could be the issue?

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto; font-size: 13.5px; ">

<table  id="myTable"  style="width: 1280px;" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="font-size:10px"scope="col" width= "4%"></th>
      <th style = "writing-mode: tb-rl; transform: rotate(-180deg); text-align: center; -ms-transform:rotate(-180deg); -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);  -webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg);  -o-transform:rotate(-180deg);" rowspan="99" scope="col" width= "2%">LINE UP (7:40-8:05)</th>

      <th style="text-align: center;"  scope="col"; width= "15%;  vertical-align: middle; ">PERIOD 1 (65 Min.)<br>8:10 – 9:15</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;"  scope="col" width= "15%">PERIOD 2 (65 Min.)<br>9:15 – 10:20</th>
      <th  style = "writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: rotate(-180deg);   text-align: center;" rowspan="99" scope="col" width= "2%">BREAK 35 minutes (10:20 – 10:55 )</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;"  scope="col" width= "15%">PERIOD 3 (65 Min.)<br>10:55 - 12:00</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;"  scope="col" width= "15%">PERIOD 4 (60 Min.)<br>12:00 - 1:05</th>
      <th style = " writing-mode: vertical-rl; transform: rotate(-180deg);   text-align: center;" rowspan="99" scope="col" width= "2%">BREAK 40 minutes (1:00 pm - 1:45 pm)</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;"  scope="col" width= "15%">PERIOD 5 (60 Min.)<br>1:45 – 2:45</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" scope="col" width= "15%">PERIOD 6 (45 Min.)<br>2:45 – 3:30</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: write your code

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Sorry. I just edited the question. Please check